# Lazy loading Properties in swift

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to wrap my head around the Swift language.  A common pattern when building views in code with Objective-C is to override UI properties and lazy load them like so:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *myLabel;

- (UILabel *)myLabel
{
     if (!_myLabel) {
         _myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 75.0f, 320.0f, 20.0f)];
        [_myLabel setFont:[UIFont subHeadlineFont]];
        [_myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor subHeadlineColor]];
        [_myLabel setText:@"Hello World"];
     }
     return _myLabel;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myLabel];
}
```

This allows for the configuration  of UIElements to be self contained within their setup but doesn't result in reconfiguring them every time.

It seems we don't have access to the backing store in Swift and the `@lazy` keyword doesn't really have the same semantics.

I'm curious if anyone has identified a similar pattern in Swift that allows one to keep the configuration of variables and constants together with their declaration in a neat syntactic way that doesn't result in reconfiguration every time?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I think a `lazy` property initialized with a closure would work:

```
lazy var myLabel: UILabel = {
    var temporaryLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    ...
    return temporaryLabel
}()
```

As I read “The Swift Programming Language.” (Checkerboard example) the closure is only evaluated once).

Comment: A lazy attribute must be a `var` and cannot be `let`

Comment: The internal temporaryLabel CAN be a let though, apparently without any ill consequences.

Comment: awesome, so does this mean that once myLabel has been initialized, it will not reinitialize it over again, or generate a new instance of UILabel but will return the UILabel instance first initiated?

Comment: The closure will only execute once.

Comment: @ChristianOtkjær,    lazy var imageObj: UIImage! = {
        
        if(self.imageURL != nil){
            var imageData :  NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.imageURL, options: nil, error: nil)
            self.image = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
        }
        return self.image
    }().i am using this code for image loading but i can not get image here.

Comment: You should not access the self.image in the closure. Make a temporary UIImage and return it from the closure and it will be assigned to self.image automatically. Make sure that imageUrl is set before trying to access the self.image, otherwise the closure will return nil and it will never be invoked again.

Comment: Why do we have parentheses after property's closure ?

Comment: To evaluate the closure. The closure is of type "(​​) -> ​UILabel​". But the property "myLabel" is of type "UILabel". So, when myLabel is needed for the first time, the closure needs to be evaluated and the return value assigned to "myLabel".

Answer (score 6):

```
class Thingy {
    init(){
        println("making a new Thingy")
    }
}

var thingy = {
    Thingy();
}()

println("\(self.thingy)")
println("\(self.thingy)")
```

The log message "making a new Thingy" appears just once, proving that only one Thingy was created - the closure was called only once, namely to initialize this property. This is effectively what you are describing. All you have to do is add more to the closure so as to configure it the returned object.

If you make the var `@lazy` and comment out the `println` statements, *no* Thingy is created, proving that the laziness does what it is intended to do; you could omit this, however, since you know that the label will in fact always be needed early on. The point of `@lazy` is to prevent the closure from *ever* being called unless the getter is called, but you are always going to call the getter so that is pointless in your situation.

Comment: This is the best answer so far from an explanation point of view, although Christian also points out that the Closure is only evaluated once in "The swift programming language". Though let's imagine a button for which I want to call `_myButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)` wouldn't that capture self in the context of the closure?

Comment: In Swift there's no danger, as there is closure syntax that prevents the strong capture of whatever you want to prevent the capture of. Much simpler than the "weak-strong dance" we used to have to do.

Comment: But in any case there's no such worry here. You only have to worry if a closure mentions self and self retains the closure. No one is retaining this closure. It's called, that's all. (The equals sign is to receive the _result_ of the closure. The closure itself is merely a convenient way of writing a function.)

Comment: Ok, based on your explanation I believe this is the correct way to go, I'm still running into some syntax errors when I remove the `@lazy` prefix because I don't think `self` remains equivalent once I'm inside the closure.  I'll keep trying to work on the syntax errors and update the original when I've figured it out. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: @BrentWestmoreland Right, I see why. You are not allowed to refer to self until the instance has been initialized. But unless you use `@lazy` we _are_ initializing (we are in the middle of it). Thus despite what I said in my answer you will have to keep `@lazy` - which does no harm in any case. Very interesting! And that way of doing it is actually closer to your original.

Comment: Whoa! Ok, now I get it.  We're losing the race during initialization that is handled by the `@lazy` keyword.  In that case, I think I need to award the green checkmark to the first bloke to respond with the correct answer, but major kudos for talking through it.  Thanks @Matt!

Comment: No problem, it's your checkmark! Actually the real first correct responder was Cezar who then deleted his answer. What was wrong with it was that he tried to use a function self.configureMyLabel() but, as we've just seen, you can't refer to self yet to fetch the function. It would need to be kept elsewhere, or you can use a closure.

Comment: Why do we have parentheses after property's closure ? I thought it could be ommited, right ?

Comment: @PhamHoan `{}` defines an anonymous function. `{}()` defines an anonymous function and calls it.

Comment: thx @matt, it's clear now. So that sample in Apple's Swift Language Guide may be wrong. (at ARC -> Strong Reference Cycles for Closures)

Comment: @PhamHoan Not, it's not wrong. We are defining a variable whose default value is result of _calling_ a function. Apple is defining a variable whose default value _is_ a function.

Comment: @matt How is it pointless? Apple does it for `UIViewController`'s `view` too, even though it is always going to be needed.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr You may have misunderstood what I said. I'm just talking about a Swift language feature - it has nothing to do with the overall _pattern_. I'm saying the OP does not need a `@lazy` var attribute (now renamed `lazy`) in this particular case in order to implement the pattern. However, this could be just coincidence; `lazy` is needed in this pattern if the variable's initializer makes any reference to `self`, which happens a lot. See my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_lazy_initialization.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty much the Swift version as your ObjectiveC example. (simplified to use an `Int` rather than a view)

```
class Foo {
    var _value: Int?
    var value: Int {
        get {
            if !_value {
                _value = 123
            }
            return _value!
        }
    }
}

Foo().value //-> 123
```

Though it's not very pretty.

Comment: Yeah, I COULD declare TWO variables to load every UIElement I want to put on the screen lazily, but the pattern isn't really the same is it. As you mention, it's not very pretty.

Comment: Except this is valuable if you need to reset the variable by setting it to nil.

Comment: But otherwise you couln't override `lazy`

Answer (score 4):

Apple seems to be doing it differently... If I create a new project in Xcode and add Core Data, there's an example of it in the `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel {
    if !_managedObjectModel {
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MyApp", withExtension: "momd")
        _managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
    }
    return _managedObjectModel!
}
var _managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel? = nil
```

Though, this reads to me as the variable is created on initialization, however just read subsequently and `@lazy` seems like a nicer implementation. Any thoughts?

So I tried this:

```
class TestClass {
    @lazy var myLabel : UILabel = {
        var temporaryLabel : UILabel = UILabel()
        return temporaryLabel 
    }()

    var testLabel: UILabel {
    if !_testLabel {
        _testLabel = UILabel()
        }
    return _testLabel!
    }
    var _testLabel: UILabel? = nil

    func test () {
        println(myLabel)
        println(self.testLabel)
    }
}
```

And both are indeed just created lazily. As @bradlarson [points out on Twitter](https://twitter.com/bradlarson/status/477481695294148608):

> @runmad The one thing that your approach preserves is the read-only
>   state of the property. @lazy can’t be used with let, which is an
>   issue.

Comment: The way to write this with @lazy would be, is not very intuitive.  I'd rather use Apple's method.
`
 @lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {() -> NSManagedObjectModel in
  var _managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel? = nil
  let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("SwiftCD", withExtension: "momd")
  _managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
  return _managedObjectModel!;
 }()
`

Comment: One thing though.  If you use @lazy, you pretty much need to ensure it’s safe. You don’t get another chance at it. With Apple’s template, if nil is returned by the creator, it will try again next time to create the object.

Comment: Please note that Apple's template _does_ now use `lazy`.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a variant to Christian Otkjær's answer it is also possible to assign a class method to the @lazy var:

```
class MyClass {

  @lazy var myLabel : UILabel = MyClass.newLabel()

  class func newLabel() -> UILabel {
    var temporaryLabel : UILabel = UILabel()
    ...
    return temporaryLabel
  }
}
```

It's effectively the same as using a closure but in case there are too many lines of code in the closure, it's an option to put that code in a class method somewhere else after the declaration of all properties and initialization methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a closure on your @lazy variable to declare how it should be created:

```
class Blah {
    @lazy var label: () -> UILabel = {
        var view:UILabel = UILabel();
        //Do stuff here
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case your `label` is a `func`, I think you need to remove the `() ->`

Comment: The () -> UILabel should be inside the curly bracket followed by in, and () should be after the closing curly bracket...

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 3.0

I prefer this inline style.

```
lazy var myLabel: UILabel = self.createMyLabel()

private func createMyLabel() -> UILabel {
    let mylabel = UILabel()
    // ...
    return mylabel
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it gives an error: Use of unresolved identifier 'self'.   On the lazy var line.