# How to properly implement lazy instantiation with an @IBOutlet property in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift

I am Learning iOS Development with Big Nerd Ranch's latest iOS book. I have chosen to implement their apps in Swift. In one of their apps, they have the following code in Objective C:

```
- (UIView *)headerView
{
    // If you have not loaded the header view yet...
    if (!_headerView) {

        // Load HeaderView.xib
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil]
    }

    return _headerView;
}
```

Apple's Swift guide on "@IBOutlet":

> When you declare an outlet in Swift, the compiler automatically converts the type to a weak implicitly unwrapped optional and assigns it an initial value of nil. In effect, the compiler replaces @IBOutlet var name: Type with @IBOutlet weak var name: Type! = nil.

As it was pointed out in [Lazy loading Properties in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068829/lazy-loading-properties-in-swift), there are a couple of different options. None of them in that post explicitly mention lazy initialization with @IBOutlet, so I've done by best to implement their suggestions, and would like to know what would be considered best practices.

Attempt #1(failed): following a similar pattern, as the example from AppDelegate.swift. This brings the issue "'IBOutlet' attribute requires property to be mutable"

```
@IBOutlet var headerView : UIView  {
    // If the HeaderView has not been loaded yet...
    if !_headerView {
        // Load HeaderView.xib
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)
    }
        return _headerView!
}
var _headerView : UIView? = nil
```

Attempt #2(failed): using any variation of "@lazy" with "@IBOutlet" didn't worked because "@lazy" needs an initializer, but if a closure is used, then "@IBOutlet" has the same issue as from Attempt #1

Attempt #3(successful?): this is the only way I was able to get this to work. I got the idea from a somewhat different question, [Lazy property initialization in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107938/lazy-property-initialization-in-swift). My understanding of what is happening is headerView is actually declared as "@IBOutlet weak var headerView : UIView! = nil", will only be initialized once with the TableViewController subclass I have, and that initialization will be "lazy" in that it only occurs when the TableViewController needs to be loaded.

```
@IBOutlet var headerView : UIView

func loadHeaderView() {
    // If the HeaderView has not been loaded yet...
    if !headerView {
        // Load HeaderView.xib
        println("loaded HeaderView")
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadHeaderView()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

So, how can this be improved?

Is viewDidLoad() the correct function to use?

Thanks

Comment: Typically we use `IBOutlet` when we're planning to hook up a property in Interface Builder - if this is all going to be done in code it seems like it would be better practice to declare the property attributes explicitly.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm kinda just mindlessly following the Big Nerd Ranch book right now. I think they were showing how it is another option to do things this way

Comment: @SchoonSauce Loading a nib into a property at runtime is not the same thing as hooking up objects from a nib, which is what IBOutlet does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't actually providing a closure for `headerView` with that code, you're declaring it as a read-only computed property. `@IBOutlet` properties need to be mutable so the XIB/Storyboard can do its magic, so you'd need to implement it with both a getter and a setter, like this:

```
@IBOutlet var headerView : UIView {
get {
    if !_headerView {
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)
    }
    return _headerView!
}
set {
    _headerView = newValue
}
}
var _headerView : UIView? = nil
```

Comment: So would this be preferable to the way I implemented it in Attempt #3, and if so, then why? Thanks

Comment: Well, the method in my answer seems a bit messy since we can't declare `_headerView` as a private property yet, but you don't have to remember to initialize the view before using it, which I think is the goal. With #3, if there's a different route to `headerView` being used (I don't think there is in this case, but just sort of what if), then you'll have a runtime error because you're trying to work with a `nil` optional.

Answer (score 7):

A lazily loaded outlet makes no sense- if it's an outlet, it's populated when loading the nib, not from code. If you're loading it from code, it doesn't need to be an outlet, so you can use @lazy.

Comment: It can be a good design to define a `ViewController` ou `UIView` class, that allow it's user configurations options.  
  
Maybe i want to design a class which you can reference in interface-builder. assign a `IBOutlet` variable to something you want custom, but in case you don't the class would configure by itself.

Answer (score 4):

The following works...

```
@IBOutlet lazy var headerView : UIView? = {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
    }()
```

then set the headerView

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a didSet:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView! {
        didSet {
            profileImageView.image = profileImage
            profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        }
    }
```